# how to generate a ER diagram for oracle tables with out having foreign key constraint

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, erd

Is there any way or a software to generate ER diagrams for oracle tables with out having foreign key constraint ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have unique indexes? Otherwise, manually is the only answer I'm aware of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117774/decipher-database-schema may help

Answer (score 0):

Use [Linkifier](https://github.com/janmotl/linkifier), which estimates the foreign key constraints for Oracle and has an export into yEd or Oracle Data Modeler for ER-diagram plotting.