# Create a catalog of a DB schema (Java)

Tags: java, sql, database, graph, jgrapht

With this question I hope to get some ideas to start solving my 'problem'.

So, I need to **"catalog" a Database Schema**: all the **tables** that exist, with the **relationships** between them. 
I'm developing my project in `JAVA`, so I'd like to continue with it. I would like to, after I have that catalog, query it with some tables names, and get the relations between them.
My idea is to have a kind of **Graph**, where the Vertexes are the DB Tables, and the Edges show the relationships between them. I began to look at `JGraphT library`. But it is possible with that to "assign" some information to the edges?

The Graph was just a starting point. If you can advise me to use another structure, I'll be glad to 'hear' more options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185967/generate-an-e-r-diagram-by-reverse-engineering-a-database , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117774/decipher-database-schema#117919

Comment: Thanks, it gives me an idea of what to look for: Graph Databases Projects. I'm reading about Neo4j. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I made some ER diagrams by hand before but never tried to automate it based off existing schema; I've usually done it the other way around. I just found those questions with a quick search.